# how to find related products

Tags: database-design, e-commerce

I have a table storing various bikes:

```
**tbl_bikes**
pk id
   name
fk brand_id
   price
   speedometer
   mileage
   .... other properties
```

I have a view bike page which show detail information of particular bike record.
I want to display a block with related bikes as I have seen in other ecommerce sites. How do these ecommerce sites or like magento display products related to particular product item. Do I need to change my database table structure? How can I achieve this? On what basis are the related products fetched ?

Comment: I could imagine you might want to give some more information.

I would guess you could add a property type or something to show other bikes that have the same type. Or bikes within a same price range. Or bikes from the same brand.

I think you have several options.

Comment: The more sophisticated shopping sites also have a "other customers have also viewed..." option.  If you're tracking the activity of your site users then you can pick the top _n_ bikes that were also viewed by other customers for any given bike.  This way you're letting your customers decide what makes bikes similar rather than you making an arbitrary decision.

Comment: thanks i will go with this solution for my (You may also like)products block